# How does allure get the test status in categories.json

Tags: report, allure

After executing test I am getting the XML files in `allure-results` directory. From there I am generating the HTML report using the command:

```
allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report
```

In `allure-results` I have a `categories.json` file, which is used to categorize tests in the HTML report based on its result (eg: passed, broken, failed, ...). I believe this categorization is done by allure.

So I want to know on what basis allure does this categorization.

**categories.json**

```
{
  "name": "Ignored tests",
  "messageRegex": ".*ignored.*",
  "matchedStatuses": [ "skipped" ],
  "flaky": true
},
{
  "name": "Infrastructure problems",
  "traceRegex": ".*RuntimeException.*",
  "matchedStatuses": [ "broken", "failed" ]
},
{
  "name": "Outdated tests",
  "messageRegex": ".*FileNotFound.*",
  "matchedStatuses": [ "broken" ]
},
{
  "name": "Passed",
  "messageRegex": ".*",
  "matchedStatuses": [ "passed" ]
}
```

Sample test report image:

[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me what the issue is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Bunnynut I have included more details.

Comment: On the basis of the `matchedStatuses` and `messageRegex` matches of tests?

Answer (score 2):

`categories.json` should be a list of mappings.

In your case it should looks like

```
[
  {
    "name": "Ignored tests",
    "messageRegex": ".*ignored.*",
    "matchedStatuses": ["skipped"],
    "flaky": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Infrastructure problems",
    "traceRegex": ".*RuntimeException.*",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken", "failed"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Outdated tests",
    "messageRegex": ".*FileNotFound.*",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Passed",
    "messageRegex": ".*",
    "matchedStatuses": ["passed"]
  }
]
```